# Update Select2 Widget Dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

So I'm using **YII 1 framework** (against my will) and trying to update a select2 widget dynamically using jquery.

**The widget**

```
$this->widget('booster.widgets.TbSelect2', [
    'asDropDownList' => false,
    'name'           => 'target',
    'val'            => $val,
    'options'        => ['data' => []],
    'htmlOptions'    => ['class' => 'target-select', 'id' => 'service']
])
```

**The jquery**

```
$.each(response.html, function(key,value) {
    target.append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.text+'</option>');
});
```

I have the element rendering fine on the page, with no options inside it.
An ajax request retrieves some options that must be placed **inside the select**, but this just appends the options as text after the element and NOT inside the element.

Any ideas how to get these options inside the select?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with the jQuery so it seems like your `target` is not pointing to your `<select>`. Perhaps posting a little more of your JavaScript code would help?

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. see my answer. I think "service" is the id of the select based on the information in the question. @Donal.Lynch.Msc Could you post the html of the select element?

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('#service').append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.text+'</option>
```